# Nvidia fails to install on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I tried to update Nvidia both via manually and Geforce,  I ran the installation as you normally would only to be met with the error "NVIDIA Installer Failed", and it told me the "Graphics Driver" failed to install.

**I've tried:**

Removed old drivers using DDU
Geforce update 
Manual installer from the Nvidia Website with clean installation options

BTW I was able to extract the logs out of the Nvidia installer it said something timed out Could someone analyze these logs Please?:
[Nvidia installer log .zip download link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-BLpFdJY9TyOTJyYVJ4a2F4cmM/view?usp=sharing)

**PC SPECS**

```
Operating System:
Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit SP1

CPU:
Intel Core i7 6700HQ @ 2.60GHz
Skylake 14nm Technology


RAM:
16.0GB

Motherboard:
Micro-Star International Co. Ltd. MS-16J5 (U3E1)

Graphics:
Generic PnP Monitor (1920x1080@48Hz)
Intel HD Graphics 530 (MSI)
2047MB NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M (MSI)
ForceWare version: 376.33
SLI Disabled

Storage:
931GB Hitachi HGST HTS721010A9E630 SCSI Disk Device (SATA)
4657GB Seagate BUP BK USB Device (USB (SATA))

Optical Drives:
HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GUD0N SCSI CdRom Device

Audio:
Realtek High Definition Audio
```

Comment: you get a timeout: **1637@CNVDevicePhase::InstallHelper : Device phase failure Exception {0x800705b4 - This operation returned because the timeout period expired.}**

Comment: Do you know what it means though ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IT was the Anti virus it interfered and keeped on removing the files that Nvidia's trying to install

Comment: What AV it would would be useful to know. The process of finding out it was the AV would round out the answer.

Comment: ok, AV suites can cause timeouts. Which AV do you use?

Comment: AVG internet security

Comment: That sounds about right for AVG... it seems to have an "I've got no clue what's dangerous & what isn't, so I'll quarantine everything & not bother to tell the user" mentality. I'd sack it & get something better.

Comment: IS advast any better ?

Comment: Pick something from the top of the list at https://www.av-test.org/en/antivirus/home-windows/ when sorted by Protection [paying attention to the other columns too] Check back over previous results to see who is always near the top. Ones I've noticed stay there over the years are BitDefender, Kaspersky & F-Secure. A lot of the others come & go.